# Find function in a tree

Tags: c, function, depth-first-search

I have a problem with a function that should find all the nodes in a tree that have the same name and I have to save the path for every node found.

I have implemented my function with an algorithm based on the Depth-First-Search but the problem is that the path saved is incomplete. For Example the node is in the path `/dir0rid/dir0rid/dir1rid/file1` and the function save just the path `/dir1rid/file1`.

This is my function:

```
void find(node_t *Fs) {
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 1024) {
        if (Fs->figli[i] != NULL) {
            if (Fs->figli[i]->nome_file == NULL) {
                i++;
            } else {
                if (strcmp(Fs->figli[i]->nome_file, "DELETED") != 0) {
                    if (Fs->figli[i]->type == 1) {
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        finded[j_index] = Fs->figli[i];
                        j_index++;

                        find(Fs->figli[i]);
                        i++;
                        j_index--;
                        finded[j_index] = NULL;
                    }
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    if (hash_search(Fs, file_cercato) != NULL) {
        int j = 0;
        percorso[f_index][0] = '\0';

        while (finded[j] != NULL) {
            strcat(percorso[f_index], "/");
            strcat(percorso[f_index], finded[j]->nome_file);
            j++;
        }

        strcat(percorso[f_index], "/");
        strcat(percorso[f_index], file_cercato);
        f_index++;
        percorso[f_index][0] = '\0';
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: You *always* seem to increment i (with `i++;)` Have you considered changing the `while()`to a`for()`loop?

Comment: and what change with the `for()`  loop?

Comment: Readability mainly.

Comment: For deleted question [VHDL counter address latch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733581/vhdl-counter-address-latch), see [c_indirizzo.vhdl](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8r5sqdqq00ffmr4/c_indirizzo.vhdl?dl=1)  (on Dropbox a direct download link). Only pointers (and end_header) are assigned so the two processes can be combined, n_state becomes c_state. Without your testbench it can't be validated.

Comment: hi @user1155120 if you want i can send you the other part of code and the testbench by email, write me to gile96@icloud.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified version of the loop(I omitted the hashstuff):

---

```
void find2 (node_t* Fs){

    int i ;

    for(i=0; i < 1024; i++){
        if (Fs->figli[i] == NULL) continue;
        if(Fs->figli[i]->nome_file == NULL) continue;
        if(!strcmp(Fs->figli[i]->nome_file,"DELETED")) continue;
        if(Fs->figli[i]->type==1) continue;
        finded[j_index]=Fs->figli[i];

        j_index++;
        find(Fs->figli[i]);
        j_index--; // <<--

        finded[j_index]=NULL; // <<--
    }
}
```

---

Now, Idon't understand your logic, butI *think* the `j_index--;` is wrong. It should *probably* be placed **after** the `finded[j_index]=NULL;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. About `j_index--;` it's placed first the `finded[j_index]=NULL` because when i finished to visit all the nodes with the recursive call of `find(Fs->figli[i];)` I have to delete the actual node from the path. Finded[ ] it's a global variable of pointers that I used to trace the path of a generical node

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code:

- You should use `for` loops to simplify the index updates and make the code more readable.
- You should set `finded[j_index]` to `NULL` before calling `find` recursively or change the final loop to stop at `j_index`.

Here is a modified version:

```
void find(node_t *Fs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        if (Fs->figli[i] != NULL
        &&  Fs->figli[i]->type != 1
        &&  Fs->figli[i]->nome_file != NULL
        &&  strcmp(Fs->figli[i]->nome_file, "DELETED") != 0) {
            finded[j_index] = Fs->figli[i];
            j_index++;
            find(Fs->figli[i]);
            j_index--;
        }
    }
    if (hash_search(Fs, file_cercato) != NULL) {
        percorso[f_index][0] = '\0';
        for (j = 0; j < j_index; j++) {
            strcat(percorso[f_index], "/");
            strcat(percorso[f_index], finded[j]->nome_file);
        }
        strcat(percorso[f_index], "/");
        strcat(percorso[f_index], file_cercato);
        f_index++;
        percorso[f_index][0] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Note also that all these global variables used should be moved to a structure passed as an argument to `find()`.

Comment: thanks, I've changed the `while` with the `for`, and yes  `finded[ ]` is set to NULL in main because it's dynamically allocated

Comment: @GiampieroRepole: dynamically allocated objects are not necessarily initialized to `NULL`, if you use `malloc`, the object is uninitialized, if you use `calloc()` it is initialized to all bits 0.

Comment: @GiampieroRepole: did this code help you fix the problem?